# 'I can identify myself with' or 'I can identify with'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which is more correct?

> I can identify myself with

or

> I can identify with

Comment: I can identify myself with this ID badge.  I can identify with being locked out when I've forgotten my badge.

Comment: And how is it with identify with persons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify *with* someone, where *identify* means *sympathize*:

"I can identify with him. I am a single parent as well."

You don't typically identify **yourself** *with* someone, just *to* someone. Here, *identify* means *to establish or indicate who or what you are*.

"I had to identify myself to the police, which was a problem, as I didn't have my license with me."

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell what you're asking, but I'll give it a shot.

Both serve different purposes:

> I **can identify with** this character in the novel.
>
> I **can identify myself with** this ID badge.